# Cannot connect softphone as a FreeSwitch Extension

Tags: centos, sip, freeswitch

Having successfully configured and maintained few Asterisk based installations, I have now been provided a task to configure FreeSwitch SIP server.

**ISO downloaded from**

http://wiki.fusionpbx.com/index.php?title=CentOS_ISO

**Configuration**

- CentOS 5.4 Final
- FreeSwitch
- FusionPBX 1.0

**Steps**

1. Installed the FusionPBX iso.
2. Firewall and network configuration setup. Server IP: 192.168.0.100
3. Logged in to FusionPBX web frontend from another box. (http://192.168.0.100)
4. Created an extension 6000 with password 6000.
5. Applied the changes/restarted.

I have two softwphone clients,

1. 3cx
2. X-Lite 4

Now when I try and register the softphone to FreePBX, SIP error 408 is shown.

Please help.

Comment: Have you had a look through this link? http://www.fusionpbx.com/index.php?c=/docs.php

Comment: No, I am running it on CentOS. The above link applies to BSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the cause of the issue. A bug in FreeSwitch.

**SIP Profiles**

There are three sip profiles under the normal installation:

- external.xml
- internal.xml
- internal-ipv6.xml

For this particular case, **internal.xml** was the culprit but I am pretty sure that the problem will be the same for the other files, as well.

**Why Extensions are Not Registering?**

There are three sections in the internal.xml file, namely

```
...
<param name="rtp-ip" value="$${local_ip_v4}"/>
...
<param name="sip-ip" value="$${local_ip_v4}"/>
...
<param name="presence-hosts" value="$${domain},$${local_ip_v4}"/>
...
```

looking at which, we find two aliases:

- $${domain}
- $${local_ip_v4}

**FreeSwitch parsed both values as "127.0.0.1".**

**Solution**

I was able to solve the problem by not letting FreeSwitch decide the values for me.

```
...
<param name="sip-ip" value="192.168.0.100"/>
...
<param name="presence-hosts" value="192.168.0.100"/>
...
```

Comment: +1 for checking the parsed xml - that led to me finding an internal IP using the wrong interface

Comment: I changed that, but now Freeswitch fails to start.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds, to me, like you need to sniff the traffic between the softphone client and the server and see what's actually going on with the packets on the wire. SIP is a very human-readable protocol, and it's likely that a quick `tcpdump` trace on the server (and a trace from a suitable analog on the client, ideally) is going to give you some idea as to what's going wrong faster than poking at a "black box". Nothing beats seeing the traffic on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to use either 3cx which has support for  Windows, Android and Iphone or Xlite which is only supported on Windows and OSX, I will assume that you are running your softphones on Windows as it is the only platform in common which supports both clients.

your error is:
[408 Request Timeout](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-21.4.9)

```
   The server could not produce a response within a suitable amount of
   time, for example, if it could not determine the location of the user
   in time.  The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at
   any later time.
```

1. What ip address are you getting on your softphone client pc? 192.168.0.x?
2. Disable windows firewall on the softphone client PC.

Comment: Firewall is disabled on both CentOS server and Windows 7 completely. IP address of softphone PC is 192.168.0.99. I can ping the server on 192.168.0.100. I can also verify that ports 5060, 5080 on server are open. One more update, if I uncheck the option "Register with domain and receive calls" option in Softphone-->Account Settings menu in X-Lite 4, I can connect to server. But then I cannot dial any extension or listen to music by dialing 9664.